# '/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/projct/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap' not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, archive, react-native-fbsdk

these are the error got while archiving reactnative project in xcode 12.4. debug build is running fine in simulator. but archiving showing two error.
error 1:
`module map file '/Users/mac/Downloads/omw-pro1/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/omyproject/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap' not found`

error2:
`<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/mac/Downloads/omw-pro1/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/omyproject/PrecompiledHeaders/omyproject-Bridging-Header-swift_CYGPW5NH324E-clang_2G5TWAL1B7WNS.pch' for bridging header '/Users/mac/Downloads/omw-pro1/ios/omyproject-Bridging-Header.h'` 
tried many solutions but nothings works, like `exclude arm64`, adding `VALID_ARCH` in userdefined section removing and reinstalling node_modules and pods, but nothing works for me.
Please help me with this

Comment: you solved it??